# Не получается записать переменную в файл

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, парсер

Распарсил интернет-страницу, перекодировал её в текст. Переменную с текстом не получается записать в файл. Срабатывает исключение. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
import os
import re
import pandas as pd
import requests


class HtmlParser:
    def __init__(self, sites_file='sites_of_all.xlsx', path_to='data-result-my'):

        self.path = self.create_folder_data(path_to)
        self.err_file = os.path.join(self.path, 'errors-site-my.txt')
        self.df = pd.read_excel(sites_file)

    def create_folder_data(self, path_to):

        path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), path_to)
        try:
            os.mkdir(path)
            return path
        except FileExistsError:
            return path

    def run(self):
        for site in self.df['site_final'].values:
            site_url = 'http://'+ site.strip() if 'http://' not in site else site
            site_url = site_url.lower()
            print('Обработка сайта - ', site_url)
            try:
                r = requests.post(url = site_url, verify = False)
                site_url = r.url
                print('Обработка сайта - ', site_url)

                html = urlopen(site_url).read()

                # print(html)
                filename = os.path.join(self.path, str(site) + '.txt')
                # print(filename)
                with open(filename, "w") as fh:

                    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
                    for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
                        script.extract()
                    text = soup.get_text()
                    lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
                    chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
                    text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

                    fh.write(text)
                print('---finished')
            except:
                with open(self.err_file, "a") as f:
                    f.write(site + '\n')
                print('***error')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    h = HtmlParser()
    h.run()
```

Comment: А какое исключение срабатывает ? не все будут вставлять текст и запускать, было бы здорово если бы вы показали ошибку

Comment: Обработка сайта -  http://www.planar.com
C:\My_data\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:847: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
Обработка сайта -  https://www.planar.com/
***error
Обработка сайта -  http://fastwelcorp.com
***error

Comment: fh.write(text) если здесь меняем text на переменную html, то всё корректно записывается в файл.

Comment: @Scouser57, дополнительную информацию (текст ошибки в данном случае) нужно добавлять в сам вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в кодировке. Указание encoding='utf-8' `with open(filename, "w", encoding='utf-8') as fh` решает вопрос. Иван, спасибо за интерес к моему вопросу.